# Kubernetes image concept compared to Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Reading the [K8S images article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/), I see there support for images from Azure, Google Cloud Registry and Amazon EC.

- But, why is there no support for Docker Hub?
- Is there any sane way to process/deploy Dockerfiles/Docker images in K8S ecosystem?

Given you can run K8S containers from your Docker images - are there any backdrawals? and if yes, what is the "Dockerfile" in the K8S world?

Side note. My overall impression is that Docker is very nice to adapt in development teams because of its easiness, but in terms of high-end scalability K8S is more powerful. So is this again a new gap between Dev and Ops?..

Comment: You're listing the **private** registry support, which docker-hub is not a private registry. K8s supports docker-hub also as it's an orchestration system on top of docker.

Comment: and what if you had a Docker private registry? (which is actually same API as Hub, or). But then I do not get the point.

Comment: That's down the page in the section: "Configuring Nodes to Authenticate to a Private Repository" ...

Answer (score 3):

- k8s is a container orchestration tool
- a dockerfile is used to build an image
- k8s is able to run docker containers

One could use yaml files to [deploy containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/):

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.6.0 use extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: nginx-deployment
> spec:
>   replicas: 3
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: nginx
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: nginx
>         image: nginx:1.7.9
>         ports:
>         - containerPort: 80
> ```

Comment: so, there are no "Kubernetesfiles" for native K8S images (and therefore containers)?

Comment: Indeed. Docker images are built using Dockerfiles and docker containers could be run on k8s.

Comment: Note that Dockerfiles are a native way of making containers but the format is incredibly simple.  If you look at the manpage for systemd-nspawn they will have example commmands to bootstrap most of the major versions of linux and producing a base image with debootstrap is 3 lines.

Dockerfile is just using a docker specific DSL.